# DHCP-defined local DNS address isn't responding

Tags: dhcp, bind

I set up a bind DNS server on 10.0.0.2 on my network. named.conf looks like this:

```
options {
        directory "/var/named";
        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        auth-nxdomain yes;
        datasize default;
        listen-on-v6 { any; };

        allow-recursion { any; };
        allow-transfer { none; };
        allow-update { none; };
    version none;
    hostname none;
    server-id none;
    forwarders {
       8.8.8.8;
       8.8.4.4;
    };
    // samba DLZ key
    tkey-gssapi-keytab "/var/lib/samba/private/dns.keytab";
};
//SAMBA: allows automatic update of active directory names
dlz "AD DNS Zone" {
    database "dlopen /usr/lib/samba/bind9/dlz_bind9_9.so";
};

zone "localhost" IN {
        type master;
        file "localhost.zone";
        allow-transfer { any; };
};

zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "127.0.0.zone";
        allow-transfer { any; };
};
// Lets me do reverse lookups on LAN IPs
zone "0.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "10.0.zone";
        allow-transfer { any; };
};
// Definitions for root name servers
zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "root.hint";
};
```

When I do something like `nslookup google.com 10.0.0.2` on another machine, the DNS server returns a response like it should.

However, when I define 10.0.0.2 as a DNS server on my modem/router, (I think this is part of DHCP, but I'm not an expert so I'm probably wrong - some insight here would be appreciated too) `nslookup google.com` returns something like:

```
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Can't find server name for address 10.0.0.1: Timed out
*** Default servers are not available
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.0.0.1
```

10.0.0.1 is the address of my router.

For reference, where I am putting this address for the DNS server into my router has this description:

```
DNS Server Configuration

If 'Enable Automatic Assigned DNS' checkbox is selected, this router will accept the first received DNS assignment from one of the PPPoA, PPPoE or MER/DHCP enabled PVC(s) during the connection establishment. If the checkbox is not selected, enter the primary and optional secondary DNS server IP addresses. Click 'Save' button to save the new configuration. You must reboot the router to make the new configuration effective.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router (as usually) announces itself as DNS resolver for all your pcs in the network. Now you configured it to lookup using 10.0.0.2, which seems not possible to do so - it can only do lookups on the wan interface ("outside", "the intarwebs").

Unfortunately, it seems you cannot edit the DHCP settings, you'd have to add 10.0.0.2 as the DNS server by hand on any of your machines.

(Edit: You could - if possible - disable DHCP on your router/modem and add DHCP to that server on 10.0.0.2, that way you can push even more settings)

Comment: Why do you think my router might be trying to find a local address on the WAN side? Is there a technical reason for this, or is it probably because it's consumer grade?

Comment: I guess there are a bunch of firewall settings which block doing these lookups on the LAN side - yes, that's one of the downsides of consumer grade hardware.